# Copy Data from once cell to another cell based on conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am facing an issue in excel in driving the formulas. I have data (Year, Salary, Name) in one sheet. It is updated vertically. In another sheet, I want to get list of salary for particular year. For 2019 there may be 4 rows for salary so I want all of them one by one. Below is the data:

```
Salary  EMP Year
10000   a   2017
11500   b   2018
13000   c   2019
14500   d   2017
16000   f   2018
17500   s   2019
19000   g   2017
20500   h   2018
22000   h   2019
```

Output I require:

```
Year     2017      2018    2019
         10000 11500 13000
          14500 16000 17500
           19000 20500 22000
```

So output should contain list of data for 2019 when I enter 2019 (all rows). there may be 50 rows in actual as I have given simple example of 8 rows only.

Kindly help me on this. 
Thanks, Sharmil

I tried with pivot but it is giving total value rather than individual values. Also I tried with OFFSET, Index + Match function but it does not provide me correct output. Combination of OFFSET, Index + Match gives all rows for all single year.

Comment: Seems like a good job for pivot table. Would that be an option for you? Otherwise `SUMIF` would be able to do that job.

Comment: If your data are in, let's say, A2:C51, and your year value is in G6, use =SUMIFS(A2:A51,C2:C51,CONCATENATE("=";G6)). Just custom it to whatever you have your data.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I made a mistake in question. I need individual items list. In example given, for 2017 value should not sum but should come as 10000, 14500,19000 in separate rows. Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for the German language. *SUMMEWENN* is, indeed, *SUMIF* function. You can use a sumif Formula:

Sumif(Your criteria, Your search criterua, Your desired range to be summed)

Please see the below screenshot illustrating your example

[image]

- **Your criteria**: Range C2 to C11
- **Your search criteria**: B5 --> 2017
- **Your desired range to be summed**: A2 to A11

Answer (score 0):

**Pivot Table** is a possible solution but you will need a **helper column** to "rank" the `Year`.

Put the following formula in Cell `D2` suppose your data range is `A2:C13`:

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)
```

Dray it down to apply across rows.

Then **sort** the data range by `Year` and then by `Salary` **from Smallest to Largest**.

Then **insert a pivot table** and layout the data as shown below.

[image: Pivot Table]

The problem can also be solved by formula or power query but if a list like that is all you want I believe using Pivot Table is the most efficient way.

Let me know if you have any question. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining